# How can I display the camera in Landscape View on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using the `UIImagePickerController` to add camera functionality to my app. It is working in portrait mode. How can I add support for landscape mode?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Feel free to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), pick a username/avatar, and stay awhile!

Answer (score 0):

try using [NSNotificationCenter addObserver: for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

Subclassing the camera in uiimagepickercontroller is not allowed according to the documentation, but that doesn't mean you can't pick up the events yourself and handle rotation manually.